# Hosting a custom domain website in Raspberry Pi

Tags: node.js, web, dynamic, next.js, raspberry-pi

I made a dynamic nextjs website and everything worked as my expectations, but I can't figure out how to host it on my raspberry pi 4. I own SSL certificate and a DNS that I want to use. I would gladly accept any kind of answer that might include thirdparty web services or software such as Docker, AWS, or Replit if there is no answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this, but the most straightforward way would be to use a reverse proxy. This would allow you to host your Next.js website on your Raspberry Pi, while still being able to access it via a domain name or subdomain.

To set up a reverse proxy, you would first need to install a web server on your Raspberry Pi. The most popular choice for this would be Nginx. Once Nginx is installed, you would then need to configure it to act as a reverse proxy for your Next.js website. The final step would be to point your domain name or subdomain to your Raspberry Pi's IP address.

1. Set up a Raspberry Pi as a web server using a reverse proxy.
2. Install NGINX:

```bash
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nginx
```

2. Configure NGINX as a reverse proxy:

```bash
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
```

3. Add the following lines to the end of the file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name yourdomain.com www.yourdomain.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

4. Save the file and exit.
5. Enable the new configuration:

```bash
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/default /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```

6. Restart NGINX:

```bash
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

7. Configure an A Record for your domain to point to the IP address of your Raspberry Pi.

Comment: May I ask what does ``server_name`` stands for?

Comment: according to official docs, Server names are defined using the server_name directive and determine which server block is used for a given request. 
for reference, you can visit http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html